# TableView Cell Selection not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, ios12

Trying `MVVM` design pattern.

Created a `tableView` in `storyboard` and in `FirstViewController` added below code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuTblView: UITableView!
let menuViewModel = MenuTableViewModel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.menuTblView.dataSource = menuViewModel
    self.menuTblView.delegate = menuViewModel
    menuViewModel.delegate = self
    menuTblView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell")
    menuTblView.separatorStyle = .none
}
```

and created a `MenuTableViewModel` having the `tableviewDelegate` and `tableViewDatasource` methods.

In `MenuTableViewModel` added the `didSelectRowAt`:

```
extension MenuTableViewModel:UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate.present()
    }
}

protocol MenuTableViewModelDelegate : class {
    func present()
}
```

and created a `prototcol` to present a `SecondViewController`.

In `FirstViewController` added below code:

```
extension FirstViewController : MenuTableViewModelDelegate {
    func present() {
        let asd = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.present(asd, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is the `SecondViewController` appears after clicking the `tableViewCell` twice.

**EDIT:**

`MenuTableViewModel` code :

```
class MenuTableViewModel: NSObject {

    var delegate:MenuTableViewModelDelegate!
}
```

and in `FirstViewController - ViewDidLoad` added :

```
menuViewModel.delegate = self
```

Thanks @koropok for the solution. Added below code and it worked :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.delegate.present()
}
```

but why I have to do this.

Infact If I am adding below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    //DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.delegate.present()
    //}
}
```

then also it's working fine.

My approach is wrong or I am missing something here.

Comment: where is your delegate of MenuTableViewModel have been initiated?

Comment: @Hoven: Edited the question please check.

Comment: have your logic in present function wrap inside DispatchQueue.main.async { }